# Why does changing fragments hide my tablayout (android)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have two fragment in my app. fA and fb. fA has a toolbar, a tab layout and a viewpager. fB has a textview and an image view. When I click on some button in fA in any pager, it open fB and displays an image with some text. It opens all fine, but when I press back to return to my first fragment, I loose my tab layout. The place for the tabs is present, but no indicator or title. Can someone help?

My fA xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/primary_text" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and my class:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        titles = getTitles();

        MainActivity parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        parent.setToolbar((Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        stateListener = parent.getViewPagerStateListenerInstance();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(stateListener);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        parent.setUpTabLayout(tabLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        viewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(stateListener);
    }
```

My toolbar and my tab layout are in the fragment and are to be replaced.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Any luck fixing the issue?

Comment: No.. None so ever.. I ended up starting a new activity

Comment: actually I've fixed this problem

Comment: I thought it was a problem with my app

Comment: at least I've had the same :)

Comment: so this is like up to google to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code. It worked for me

```
viewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        }
    }, 1);
```

I do this each time on onCreateView of Fragment

Comment: I know this is dirty hack but this resolved my issue for now